# Setting title using wp_title filter

Tags: filters, title

I want to do something very simple but I'm stuck finding where in WordPress I need to perform this.

When someone on my WordPress site visits a blog post page I want the title in the blog post to replaced the title of the page.

I think I can do this with the wp_title filter hook?

I thought about something like the following :-

```
add_filter('wp_title', 'filter_pagetitle');

function filter_pagetitle($title) {
 $the_post_id    = get_the_ID();
 $the_post_data  = get_post($the_post_id);
 $title = $the_post_data->post_title;

 return $title;
}
```

However I am a bit lost as to where I put this, I thought it would need to be in loop-single.php as I want this to apply only to single pages, but I have also seen that this needs to be in functions.php within my theme?

Any help would be appreciated :-)

Rich

Answer (score 4):

Since wp_title() is usually called from the header.php file of your theme, then it runs on every page of your WordPress (frontend usually). So place the filter hook and function in your theme's functions.php file, and just check if it's a blog post before you change the title. Something like this:

```
add_filter('wp_title', 'filter_pagetitle');
function filter_pagetitle($title) {
    //check if its a blog post
    if (!is_single())
        return $title;

    //if you get here then its a blog post so change the title
    global $wp_query;
    if (isset($wp_query->post->post_title)){
        return $wp_query->post->post_title;
    }

    //if wordpress can't find the title return the default
    return $title;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I thought would work also, the issue I have is that functions.php seems to think that this isn't a single post, so just returns the $title var

Comment: it has nothing to do with the functions.php file, its called when your header.php file is included and if it has wp_title() in it.

Comment: I agree with the approach, but why not just use the `$post` global directly? i.e. `global $post; $title = $post->post_title;` I don't think there's any need to call `get_post()` here.

Comment: @ChipBennett , Yep that would work even better, i was just going along with the format of the question, updated my answer

Comment: Two other points: **1)** the [`wp_title()` template tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title) *already* returns the Post Title in the context of a single blog post or static page, so this filter is actually **redundant**. **2)** you may consider **concatenating** the returned `$title` content, so as not to stomp on Plugins or other functions (SEO Plugins, etc.) filtering the document title.

Comment: the global $post didn't work for me when I tried it, it would return an ID but it would be the ID of the latest story entered into the DB rather than the one we are viewing.

Comment: all of these comments are things that I have tried, and oddly they have not worked, I think there may be an issue with the wordpress install / theme, thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: I think you may have additional Filters already hooked to your Title. Try deactivating your Plugins and switch to Twenty Twelve, and see if the proble still exists.