# Get wp_title() from page ID into a variable

Tags: title, wp-title

I'm pretty sure that it's not possible but can I get the result of `wp_title()` into a variable if I know post's ID?

So, for instance I'm on a "blog" page and I want to have the title of "about" page in a variable (not in the `<title>` tag like in this questions: [Setting title using wp_title filter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51479/setting-title-using-wp-title-filter)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, `wp_title` works only for current post, so can be a little tricky save it in a variable for a post that is not the current.

However, `wp_title` works not only for singular post / page / cpt but also for every type of archive. So it's easy create a custom function that copy the part of the core function that regard the single post / page.

```
   function get_the_wp_title( $postid = '', $sep = '&raquo;', $seplocation = '' ) {
     if ( ! $postid ) return '';
     $post = get_post($postid);
     if ( ! is_object($post) || ! isset($post->post_title) ) return '';
     $t_sep = '%WP_TITILE_SEP%';
     $title = apply_filters('single_post_title', $post->post_title, $post);
     $prefix = '';
     if ( ! empty($title) ) $prefix = " $sep ";
     if ( 'right' == $seplocation ) { // sep on right, so reverse the order
        $title_array = explode( $t_sep, $title );
        $title_array = array_reverse( $title_array );
        $title = implode( " $sep ", $title_array ) . $prefix;
      } else {
        $title_array = explode( $t_sep, $title );
        $title = $prefix . implode( " $sep ", $title_array );
      }
      return apply_filters('wp_title', $title, $sep, $seplocation);
    }
```

Code is in large part copied fron the [core `wp_title` function](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/general-template.php#L563).

Note that all filters defined for `wp_title` also works for this function.

Comment: Thank you! That's a solution but too bad that there is no built-in function like this. Perhaps it's not that useful.

Answer (score 0):

wp_title() function has a second parameter 'display' . Set it to false to get the title in a variable :

```
<?php $variable = wp_title('&raquo;',FALSE); ?>
```

If you want to get the title by page ID :

```
<?php
$pageID = 86;
$page = get_post($pageID);
echo $page->post_title;
?>
```

Comment: Yes, but `wp_title()` also adds something like: `Page Title - Site Name`. Or it comes with a filter in functions.php in the default theme which modifies its behavior. I'd like to get this title and not page's title which can be also obtained with `get_the_title( $id );`.